# How can I get Canon PIXMA MP780 printer to print?

Tags: printing, canon

After typing sudo apt-get update, I got a message saying some files could not be fetched or were absent, or some older files might have been used. Next, after trying to install cnijfilter-mx870series, or any other series (such as pixusip4100series), it said that package could not be found.
I'm having no luck.
Charles

I tried that. It said "no matches found" for the Canon PIXMA MP780. Then the next window said the printer was either "unplugged or turned off." Still stuck.
Charles

I tried the gimpprint, but when I gave the command to unpack the gutenprint file, I received a message, "cannot open; no such file or directory."
Charles

I tried it again; it said, "this does not look like a tar archive" . Am I missing something?
Charles

Comment: Are you able to open 'Printers' from the System Settings?? If so, look at the properties of your printer, and try using different driver by choosing from the 'browse' button.

Comment: It looks like there is a driver for the printer on this site:
http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/p_Supported_Printers.php
Scroll down to find the canon section.

Comment: Quote: "Gutenprint is the print facility for the GIMP, and in addition a
 suite of drivers that may be used with common UNIX spooling systems
 using GhostScript or CUPS. These drivers provide printing quality
 for UNIX/Linux on a par with proprietary vendor-supplied drivers in
 many cases, and can be used for many of the most demanding printing
 tasks. Gutenprint was formerly known as Gimp-Print."

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and type the following command

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon

Then

> sudo apt-get update

You will be able to download the drivers for the PC utilizing the drivers for the ip4100 by using the following command

> sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-pixusip4100series

and then to get Ubuntu to recognize and configure the MP780, open a browser and use this URL...

> http://127.0.0.1:631/

which should open CUPS 1.5.0 administration, click on Adding Printers and Classes then the Add Printer button...

Here you should see all local printers if they are connected and turned on.

Select the MP780 and "continue"...

Then fill in or change the printer information, &c, "Continue"...

Then select Canon PIXMA MP780 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.7(en) for the model, and finally press the "Add Printer" button....

Then You can set the default options and finally hit the button...

Ubuntu should pop up a message about the new printer and it should be shown in System Settings / Printers.

Good Luck!

Comment: if you have 13.04+ you'll need to update the entry in source.list.d to quantal since the repo doesn't seem to be maintained any longer